# Android browser crashes on Facebook mobile web

Tags: android, mobile, web, facebook-login

I'm trying to build a mobile facebook web app and I'm trying to debug the login and authorize features of the javascript SDK. When my app redirects the mobile browser to facebook for authorization the mobile browser crashes when loading the mobile facebook web login page. This also happens on thier "hackbook" sample. I'm using android 2.3 gingerbread's stock browser. Dolphin browser also crashes. Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Facebook API! The crappiest and more instable platform to develop with ever.
You had a good testing reflex: go on an official demo sample and see if you can replicate the bug. If so, then it means you can't do anything about it but wait for FB to fix their code.

Just for testing, would you mind give this URL a try?
http://www.remi-grumeau.com/projects/emy/demos/facebook/

This has been tested ok on iOS5&6, Android 2.3&4, Blackberry 6&7, WindowsPhone8.

Remi